Wasm works in dev but during build Wasm file is lost
I am working with a wasm library from Manifold-3d. I am able to import it during dev, but in the build directory this gets lost.
import init from "./built/manifold?init";

let newWasm = await init().then((instance) => {
  console.log("THIS IS IT INIT ", instance);
  instance.setup();
  return instance;
});


failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/XXX/GitHub/YYYY/.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/geo/manifold.wasm'
Aborted(Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, o
'/Users/neerajsethi/Dropbox/GitHub/XXX/.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/geo/manifold.wasm'). Build with -sASSERTIONS for more info.

Is there any way to ensure that this file is found in build as well?

First fix your caps lock key - ALL CAPS is taken as SHOUTING at us - what did we do to you?

Does adding the .wasm extension to the import matter?

Got it fixed. I will post what i did.
